# Inverted texture caused from SKAction following a CGPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

"orientToPath:YES" is causing the texture of an `SKSpriteNode` to be rotated 180 degrees while it follows the path. I still want the node's `zRotation` to adjust while following the path, but I want the texture to be facing its original direction.

```
SKAction *path = [SKAction followPath:cgpath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: rotate the source image by 180 degrees, using an image program

Comment: Load image into the Preview app, select the Flip Horizontal option from the Tools menu, and save the image.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modifying the source image?

Comment: Add the node as a subview of another, rotated by 180 degrees. Then move the parent node along the path.

Comment: From Apple's documentation "Use game logic and art assets that match Sprite Kit’s coordinate and rotation conventions. This means orienting artwork to the right. If you orient the artwork in some other direction, you need to convert angles between the conventions used by the art and the conventions used by Sprite Kit. For example, if the artwork is oriented upward, then you add PI/2 radians to the angle to convert from Sprite Kit’s convention to your art’s convention and vice versa."

Comment: Yes, I have seen that part in the documentation. It doesn't really make a difference if I change the angle (done with zRotation) before hand because "orientToPath" will always flip the texture upwards. I'm just curious if this is a bug with "orientToPath" or there is a way to enforce the direction of textures for all sprites somewhere in a pList or something?

Comment: Which way is your character facing in the image?

Comment: My character is facing downwards. I just want to add that the sprite is not being flipped but rather rotated 180 degrees regardless of its original orientation.

Comment: Try adding an nslog to your update method to see what the values of zRotation is when the action is running.

Comment: Just the beginning of the change in zRotation for the sprite:
 0.000000
-3.684089
-3.680121
-3.676720
-3.672681
…

The texture orientation is still rotated 180 degrees right from the start.

Comment: If your texture was facing right, it would be oriented correctly.

Comment: No, even when it is facing the right, it is rotated 180 degrees. Setting "orientToPath" equal to "Yes" causes an 180 degree rotation regardless of the original orientation. It seems this is a bug with spritekit more than anything or there is a way to force a specific orientation for all textures which spritekit will recognize.

Comment: Which direction is your path supposed to take? From the rotation, it should be moving from right to left.

Comment: It is headed downwards on a randomly generated bezier path.

Comment: I implemented a simple followPath SKAction and found that the image used for the sprite's texture needs to be pointing upward to have the correct orientation. You can use the Preview app to flip your image vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting your sprite node's yScale to -1 will flip the texture vertically. Your sprite should then be oriented correctly along the path.